# Disable vertical "pulling" on ion-slides

Tags: ionic-framework, ion-slides

Is there a way to disable the vertical "pulling" (like swiping down/up) with the ion-slides component? Right now my onboarding slides feels a bit wobbly because vertical tracking is also handled when siping to a prev/next slide. I couldn't find anything in the docs about this.